# Using Disqus / reCaptcha in a Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, meteor, recaptcha, disqus, meteorite

I'm working on an application using Meteor. I am trying to use reCaptcha on one of my forms, and also the Disqus comments system on some of my pages. But the problem is, none of these are being rendered when I run the meteor server.

Here's the sample Disqus code I'm adding to my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'HIDDENfromstackoverflow'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

For this, only the text "**comments powered by Disqus**" shows up on the webpage.

For the reCaptcha:

```
  <noscript>
     <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=HiddenFromStackOverflow"
         height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
     <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
     </textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
         value="manual_challenge">
  </noscript>
```

It's interesting to note that the reCaptcha is displayed if I open my template as a normal HTML file in the browser (and not via the Meteor server.)

What am I missing?

Comment: i think it isn't good idea to put js script into template. Put it into head tag.

Comment: but disqus and captcha require the script to be placed where you want them to be displayed.

Comment: @Siddharh Gupta: are you sure that elements are in DOM of your web? Try to use some web inspector (firebug in firefox etc.) and look if the elements are really in DOM or meteor is ignoring them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need jquery included for this.

**public/disqus.js**

```
 /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'HIDDENfromstackoverflow'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
```

**app.html**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
</head>

<body>
{{>captcha}}
</body>

<template name="captcha">
    {{#isolate}}
     <div id="my-disqus">
        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a> 
    </div>
    {{/isolate}}
</template>
```

**client/main.js**

```
Meteor.startup (function () {

    $(function () {
        var el = document.createElement("script");
        el.src = "/disqus.js";
        el.type = 'text/javascript';
        $("#my-disqus").prepend(el);

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! The disqus widget now works. But how do I get the reCaptcha to work?

Comment: @SiddharthGupta: i think it should work normal, just remove that noscript, because then the body of that tag is rendered only if javascript is disabled and that is really usefull, if you are using meteor :D

Comment: It's working now, but without the styles. Looks very plain, but atleast it works! Thank You! :)