# ReCaptcha CSS not applied in Meteor

Tags: meteor, recaptcha

I'm trying to insert the reCaptcha in a meteor Template.

The ReCaptcha works but it doesn't have any css styles and the configuration keys are not applied.

I've added the config script before the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
     theme : 'white',
     lang : 'en'
 };
</script>
```

and inside the form I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcBoO8SAAAAAKNgu2AWLuAiqzgM0CSAywJJzCwU">
</script>
<noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcBoO8SAAAAAKNgu2AWLuAiqzgM0CSAywJJzCwU"
                height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
               value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

Comment: It seems that other people have encountered this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150201/using-disqus-recaptcha-in-a-meteor-application   (the last comment)

Comment: make sure your javascript `<script>` code is not in a `<template ></template`

Comment: Thank you Akshat for your response. Can you please show me a small example (client side and server side code) how to make recaptcha work in meteor?

Comment: Tried to put it out of the template at it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Tried to put the above code and its form container out of the template at it doesn't show up at all. It shows up only when I put it in the head tag. I think it's because meteor has a `special` way to load scripts. The script tag shows up in the DOM but inside it it says: Reload the page to get the source for: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcBoO8SAAAAAKNgu2AWLuAiqzgM0CSAywJJzCwU" 
A working example with recaptcha in meteor would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made the recaptcha show with CSS by using the recaptcha AJAX API.
In the HTML template I added the following code in the form:

```
<div class="captcha-container">
    <div id="rendered-captcha-container"></div>
</div>
```

In the client.js file I loaded the script after the template is rendered.
Waited for the script to load then created the recaptcha:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
     $.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js', function() {

        Recaptcha.create('add_your_public_key_here', 'rendered-captcha-container', {
            theme: 'red',
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });

    });    
}
```